# Getting to print a character on the screen in assembly language

Tags: assembly, char, avr, atmel, atmega

I am currently working on learning the AVR assembly language. I am using the last version of AVR Studio and I am working with the ATmega124.

Is there anyway to print a character to the screen/terminal? I have been trying to print just one letter, but without success. I have seen a lot of examples on AVR/C but nothing for assembly language.

Comment: This may help: http://www.avr-asm-tutorial.net/akkuload/en/akkuuart.asm

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean ATMega128?

The ATMega128 is a processor, it cannot display anything anywhere. You need to tell us a bit more about your hardware.

Do you for instance want to display something on the screen of a PC that you connect? If yes - which interfaces are available on the processor board, which one do you want to use.

Everything can be done in Assembler - the best example is that C program you just compiled on AVR Studio ... look into the .lss file created during the compiling/linking process - stored in the debug subdir of your project directory.